# Form with radio button that when checked will allow person to enter a number

Tags: radio-button

I have a form for people attending a gathering. if the select the Yes radio button I want to have then be able to enter the number of people that will be attending with a default value of one. this is the code i have so far.

```
</form>
<form class="form-reg" action="fridayreq.php" method="POST">
<fieldset style="width:700px; background-color:#FFF; border-radius:5px; padding:10px;">
<fieldset style="border-radius:10px; padding:10px 0px 10px 10px;;";>
    <br />  
    <label>ALIAS</Label><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="sassnumber" placeholder = "SASS#" value="<?php echo $sass;?>" >
    <input type="text" name= "alias" style= "font-size:18px;font-weight bold;" placeholder = "" value="<?php echo $alias;?>">
    <br />
    <label>WILL YOU ATTEND THE "Margaritaville" event Fri. Oct 13, 5:00pm ($10 CHARGE):</label><br />
    <label class="container">
    <input type="radio" name="mexicansocial" autofocus style= "font-size:24px;font-weight bold;"value="YES" /> Yes
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="container">
    <input type="radio" name="mexicansocial" autofocus style= "font-size:24px;font-weight bold;"value="NO" checked ="checked"/> No <br /><br />
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label>WILL YOU ATTEND THE "Spirits & Cigars" Fri. Oct 13, 5:00pm ($10 CHARGE):</label> <br />
    <label class="container">       
    <input type="radio" name="spiritscigars" autofocus style= "font-size:24px;font-weight bold;"value="YES" /> Yes
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="container">
    <input type="radio" name="spiritscigars" autofocus style= "font-size:24px;font-weight bold;"value="NO" checked="checked"/> No <br /><br />
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    
    </fieldset>
</fieldset>
<br />
<tr>
    <td width = "100"> </td>
    
    <br><br>
    <td>
        <div class="inputsub"><input name = "update" style="width:175px; height:50px; font-size: 18px" type = "submit" id = "submit" value = "Submit"></div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

any help is appreciated, I'm fairly new at this.

the above code is what I've tried